# Reformatting xts object based on criteria

Tags: r, xts

I have an xts object with series of monthly compounded returns of stocks in the following form:

```
       AALBERTS ABN_AMRO ABN_LNAM ACCELL_G    AEGON___  
1973-01       NA       NA       NA       NA          NA
1973-02       NA       NA       NA       NA -4.42149834
1973-03       NA       NA       NA       NA  0.03759308
1973-04       NA       NA       NA       NA -1.09827283
1973-05       NA       NA       NA       NA -7.30252682
1973-06       NA       NA       NA       NA -8.98970349
1973-07       NA       NA       NA       NA -5.59685493
:             :        :        :        :            :
:             :        :        :        :            :
```

I would like to make the following selection: select **only** those stocks, which have both valid returns data at time *t* and valid returns data in the previous *t-12* months. The stocks, which fulfil the mentioned criteria, need to be added to a separate xts object formatted in the following way:

```
1974-01    AEGON___       <mean of the values from t-12 to t>
1974-01    <other stock>  <mean of the values from t-12 to t>
1974-01    <other stock>  <mean of the values from t-12 to t>
:          :              :
1974-02    <other stock>  <mean of the values from t-12 to t>
```

So far I wasn't able to solve this issue, as my experience and understanding of R is very limited at this moment, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you want 12 month blocks then it should be t to t-11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since xts objects are a matrix with an index attribute, you can't mix types.  That means the example of what you want your result to look like is not possible.  That said, you can just use the `rollapply` function.

```
require(quantmod)
getSymbols("SPY;QQQQ")
x <- merge(ROC(Cl(SPY)),ROC(Cl(QQQQ)))
#mx <- rollapply(x, 12, mean, na.rm=TRUE)  # default align="center"
mx <- rollapply(x, 12, (mean), align="right")
head(mx)
#               SPY.Close    QQQQ.Close
# 2007-01-10           NA            NA
# 2007-01-11 0.0005932477  0.0008627708
# 2007-01-12 0.0006620534 -0.0009128343
# 2007-01-16 0.0019978226  0.0008508299
# 2007-01-17 0.0006291557 -0.0002853558
# 2007-01-18 0.0006238259 -0.0010075785
```

Comment: Ah, thanks a lot for pointing out to `rollapply`, only in my case `na.rm` needs to be set to `FALSE` (if one of the observations within the period contains `NA`, the period should be disregarded). Additional question, which I forgot to ask in the original topic (it's my first post here, apologies) is that the outcome of `mean` function needs to be placed at the end of the period, e.g. if the period is from Jan to Dec, the mean return over the whole year should be placed in Dec (in `rollapply` it is placed in June, halfway towards the end of the period). How can that be achieved?

Comment: Use `align="right"` to put the results of `mean` at the end of the rolling window.  Also note that you need to use `(mean)` instead of `mean` to keep `rollapply` from using `rollmean`, which doesn't seem to handle `NA` in the way you would want it to.